# What does tilde-greater-than (~>) mean in Ruby gem dependencies?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

What does `~>` mean in the context of Ruby gem depenedencies?

For example, when opening a legacy project in the RubyMine IDE, I get this
message

```
Gems required for project are not attached:
arel (~> 2.0.2),
rspec-expectation (~> 2.5.0)...
```

I've seen this tilde-greater-than notation elsewhere in the Ruby world (it's not
specific to RubyMine). Does this operator have a name other than the
awkward-sounding *tilde-greater-than*?

Comment: @Jörg, thanks for pointing out the duplicate. I have voted to close my question.  I have also edited the other question's title to include the words 'tilde-greater-than' to aid in text searching.

Comment: I've now heard this operator called a "twiddle-wakka", "approximate version", and "pessimistic version" (http://rubyrogues.com/045-rr-bundler-with-andre-arko/)

Comment: I call it the "squiggle rocket", as opposed to the "hash rocket" (`=>`).

Comment: I've recently heard it called a "fuzzy match" operator.

Comment: Another variant: "pessimistic versioning operator" https://www.rubytapas.com/2016/09/29/episode-447-pessimize/

Answer (score 253, accepted):

It means "equal to or greater than in the last digit", so e.g. `~> 2.3` means
"equal to 2.3 or greater than 2.3, but less than 3.0", while `~> 2.3.0` would
mean "equal to 2.3.0 or greater than 2.3.0, but less than 2.4.0".

You can pronounce it as "approximately greater than".

[§ Pessimistic version constraint](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns#pessimistic-version-constraint)

Comment: **Approximately greater than**! That makes so much sense - `~` to mean "approximately" and `>` to mean "greater than". I always thought `~>` was supposed to look like an arrow, and didn't really understand the particular choice of symbol... breakthrough.

Comment: Note that `~> 2` and `~> 2.0` behave the same and both will result in a version that matches `>= 2.0` and `< 3.0`

Answer (score 2):

it means bring any lower version equal or greater than, but not a major version.

So for example `arel (~> 2.0.2)`, will use (if availble) versions

- 2.0.2
- 2.0.3
- 2.0.? (as long as ? is >= 2)

but it won't use 2.1.?

Comment: Isn't 2.1 a minor version?

Answer (score 2):

According to the internet

> If a RubyGem dependency uses the syntax "~> 1.4.37", that means "a version greater than or equal to 1.4.37, but not 1.5 or higher." [1](http://blog.angelbob.com/posts/305-Ruby-Gem-Tilde-Dependencies---published-ruby)

In other words, for you
`arel` can be `2.1 > version >= 2.0.2` and
`rspec-expectation` can be `2.6 > version >= 2.5.0`.

Answer (score 1):

What this means is that you are expecting a gem that is version 2.0.2 or higher, but not 2.1 in the case of `arel (~> 2.0.2)`  This is done since people are not supposed to release breaking syntax changes in minor revisions. So `arel 2.0.3` would be expected to have bug/stability fixes over 2.0.2