# What does ~> mean in ruby gems dependencies?

Tags: rubygems

I went to http://rubygems.org/gems/rails and I saw that in  Runtime Dependencies
the bundler gem is defined as follows

```
bundler ~> 1.0
```

What does that mean? Thanx in advance.

Comment: Oh well, I found out that the same question has been asked before. Here's the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170547/what-does-tilde-greater-than-mean-in-ruby-gem-dependencies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It basically means greater than. or equal to, the last digit of the version.

i.e. "~> 1.0" is equivalent to ">= 1.0 and < 2.0". Thus 1.1, 1.5.2, 1.9.9 will all match.

Another example: "~> 1.1.0" would mean ">= 1.1 and < 1.2"

Refer also to: [What does tilde-greater-than (~>) mean in Ruby gem dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170547/what-does-tilde-greater-than-mean-in-ruby-gem-dependencies)