# Difference between Gemfile and Gemfile.lock in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile

I am a beginner in Ruby on Rails and I'm Using Rails4

What is the difference between Gemfile and Gemfile.lock in Rails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gemfile contains the gems that will be included in your project once you run `bundle install`. You can group them, as well as specify their origin (where they will be fetched from), and version/branch.

Gemfile.lock is generated by `bundler` and contains a list of all the gems which are actually installed and their version, and including all their dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

`Gemfile` stores list of packages you want to install for your project, with optional informations where to find them and which version to use. If you don't have `Gemfile.lock`, bundler will use informations from `Gemfile` and find packages and versions which can be installed to satisfy all dependencies.

`Gemfile.lock` is then generated to store packages and their versions used by `bundle install` (after dependencies are resolved). If someone would invoke `bundle install` again, bundler checks if `Gemfile.lock` is up to date and if it is, bundler uses versions from `Gemfile.lock` to install gems.

`Gemfile` is used to store required packages you want to use, `Gemfile.lock` stores all package names and versions used with last `bundle install`, which should work on deployment or on other developer`s machines (because they are the same versions you used in development).

Please refer to documentation: http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-install.1.html and http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-update.1.html. Check also section about deployment.

*UPDATE*:

Also in Related questions: [What is the difference between Gemfile and Gemfile.lock in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927442/what-is-the-difference-between-gemfile-and-gemfile-lock-in-ruby-on-rails?rq=1)