# Could not find gem 'jquery-rails (= 2.0.0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

So in the GemFile if I leave it as **gem 'query-rails'**  and install the bundle, it works. But if I specify the version like this:

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0'
```

and want to install or update the bundle, it doesn't work and shows the error in the title.

I also did a

```
sudo gem install jquery-rails
```

and tried again to give a version to jQuery but still didn't work.

Why?!

Comment: If you don't need `jquery version 2.0.0` leaving it without the version number is probably fine.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is no v2.0.0 jquery-rails gem available - [it was yanked](http://rubygems.org/gems/jquery-rails/versions).  You should try using 2.0.1 or later.  Generally, it's better to specify the '~>' helper to get the latest bug fixes for that minor version:

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.0.0'
```

This will install v2.0.3 which is the latest of the 2.0.x series.  Read [What does tilde-greater-than (~>) mean in Ruby gem dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170547/what-does-tilde-greater-than-mean-in-ruby-gem-dependencies) and http://semver.org/ for more info on this.

Comment: Thank you! I got stuck with this error in the Ruby on Rails Tutorial