# Ruby: How to install a specific version of a ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Using the command-line `gem` tool, how can I install a specific version of a gem?

Answer (score 1354, accepted):

Use the `-v` flag:

```
$ gem install fog -v 1.8
```

Comment: If, like me, you have previously installed a later version of your gem, then you must uninstall the later version with e.g. `gem uninstall fog`. It will ask you which version to uninstall if you have more than one.

Comment: i have 3 versions of rake: `gem list | grep rake` = `rake (10.1.1, 10.1.0, 0.8.7)`.. i got a rails 2.3.5 project and another that's 3.0 that i'm working on at the same time.. how do i use a specific version of rake for each project (ie on command line?)

Comment: @abbood `rake _10.1.1_ ...` should work, for whoever wants to know :)

Comment: Worth noting that this does not seem to affect executable binaries. Uninstalling the previous version worked for binaries though.

Comment: Once again, wishing I could do multiple upvotes. Maybe if they had to be separated by at least a year. :)

Comment: I probably search and find this once a year lol, that's how often I use it but great!

Answer (score 257):

Use the `--version` parameter (shortcut `-v`):

```
$ gem install rails -v 0.14.1
…
Successfully installed rails-0.14.1
```

---

You can also use version comparators like `>=` or `~>`

```
$ gem install rails -v '~> 0.14.0'
…
Successfully installed rails-0.14.4
```

---

With newer versions of *rubygems* you can tighten up your requirements:

```
$ gem install rails -v '~> 0.14.0, < 0.14.4'
…
Successfully installed rails-0.14.3
```

---

Since some time now you can also specify versions of multiple gems:

```
$ gem install rails:0.14.4 rubyzip:'< 1'
…
Successfully installed rails-0.14.4
Successfully installed rubyzip-0.9.9
```

But this doesn't work for more than one comparator per gem (yet).

Comment: This worked for ~>, but what if you have '< 0.9, >= 0.7' type of situation? I tried applying two v arguments and it appears as though the first was ignored. Using the a comma separator wouldn't even parse. I ended up removing the greater than requirement and it happened to install an acceptable version, but having a formal solution would be nice.

Comment: What does version comparator `~>` stand for?

Comment: It means that the last digit is allowed to grow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170547/what-does-tilde-greater-than-mean-in-ruby-gem-dependencies)

Comment: Mael Stor's answer tells us that Joseph Coco's suggested two v arguments from six years earlier now works.

Answer (score 107):

for Ruby 1.9+ use colon.

```
gem install sinatra:1.4.4 prawn:0.13.0
```

Comment: what gem (and what version) are you trying to install?

Comment: please tell me the output of `gem sources`, if it's empty, add a repo using this command: `gem sources -a https://rubygems.org/`

Comment: my `gem -v` shows `1.8.23` versus your `2.2.2`. Looks like this feature is new :)

Comment: Ruby 1.8 is already end of support https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/06/30/we-retire-1-8-7/

Answer (score 106):

For installing
`gem install gemname -v versionnumber`

For uninstall
`gem uninstall gemname -v versionnumber`

Answer (score 27):

As others have noted, in general use the `-v` flag for the `gem install` command.

If you're developing a gem locally, after cutting a gem from your gemspec:

```
$ gem install gemname-version.gem
```

Assuming version 0.8, it would look like this:

```
$ gem install gemname-0.8.gem
```

Comment: Great answer.  I suggest you add another code block for the flag "-v" option though.  As my eyes read the answer they immediately went to the code blocks and not the text surrounding it.  If others do the same they'll miss the "-v" portion.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `-v` or `--version` flag. For example

```
gem install bitclock -v '< 0.0.2'
```

To specify upper AND lower version boundaries you can specify the `--version` flag twice

```
gem install bitclock -v '>= 0.0.1' -v '< 0.0.2'
```

or use the syntax (for example)

```
gem install bitclock -v '>= 0.0.1, < 0.0.2'
```

The other way to do it is

```
gem install bitclock:'>= 0.0.1'
```

but with the last option it is not possible to specify upper and lower bounderies simultaneously.

[gem 3.0.3 and ruby 2.6.6]

Comment: How to make gem to **not upgrade dependencies**, `gem install "asciidoctor:2.0.10" "asciidoctor-diagram:2.0.5"`, always upgrade asciidoctor to a later version than 2.0.10, I've tried to use the options `--minimal-deps` and `--conservative` ? I've worked around this with `gem install --no-document --ignore-dependencies "asciidoctor-diagram:2.0.5"` but `asciidoctor-diagram` only has a single dep, how to handle that more elegantly.

Comment: @Brice I couldn't reproduce this behaviour with the command line `gem install 'asciidoctor:2.0.10' 'asciidoctor-diagram:2.0.5'`. It installs exactly these versions. Which gem version is reported when you type `gem --version`?

Comment: It happens with `gem` 3.1.4, in the `registry.fedoraproject.org/fedora-minimal` image. Using this command for example `docker run -it --rm registry.fedoraproject.org/fedora-minimal bash -c "microdnf install -y ruby; gem install 'asciidoctor:2.0.10' 'asciidoctor-diagram:2.0.5'"`, I see that first asciidoctor 2.0.10 is installed, then asciidoctor 2.0.12.

Answer (score 7):

**Linux**

To install different version of ruby, check the latest version of package using `apt` as below:

```
$ apt-cache madison ruby
      ruby |    1:1.9.3 | http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
      ruby |        4.5 | http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main amd64 Packages
```

Then install it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ruby=1:1.9.3
```

To check what's the current version, run:

```
$ gem --version # Check for the current user.
$ sudo gem --version # Check globally.
```

If the version is still old, you may try to switch the version to new by using ruby version manager (`rvm`) by:

```
rvm 1.9.3
```

Note: You may prefix it by `sudo` if `rvm` was installed globally. Or run `/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm` if your command `rvm` is not in your global `PATH`. If rvm installation process failed, see the troubleshooting section.

---

Troubleshooting:

- If you still have the old version, you may try to install rvm (ruby version manager) via:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install curl # Install curl first
  curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby # Install only for the user.
  #or:# curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable --ruby # Install globally.
  ```

  then if installed locally (only for current user), load rvm via:

  ```
  source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm; rvm 1.9.3
  ```

  if globally (for all users), then:

  ```
  sudo bash -c "source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm; rvm 1.9.3"
  ```
- if you still having problem with the new ruby version, try to install it by rvm via:

  ```
  source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm && rvm install ruby-1.9.3 # Locally.
  sudo bash -c "source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm && rvm install ruby-1.9.3" # Globally.
  ```
- if you'd like to install some gems globally and you have rvm already installed, you may try:

  ```
  rvmsudo gem install [gemname]
  ```

  instead of:

  ```
    gem install [gemname] # or:
    sudo gem install [gemname]
  ```

> Note: It's prefered to NOT use sudo to work with RVM gems. When you do
>   sudo you are running commands as root, another user in another shell
>   and hence all of the setup that RVM has done for you is ignored while
>   the command runs under sudo (such things as GEM_HOME, etc...). So to
>   reiterate, as soon as you 'sudo' you are running as the root system
>   user which will clear out your environment as well as any files it
>   creates are not able to be modified by your user and will result in
>   strange things happening.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to installing, you can check the available versions with the list command.

```
gem list ^[gemname]$ --remote --all
gem install [gemname] -v [version]
```