# Is page object 'select list' deprecated?

Tags: ruby, windows, cucumber, pageobjects

I have been using the page-object gem and I am getting a DEPRECATION WARNING when trying to use `select_list(:my_name, :id => 'foo')`.  Should I not use select list?

page-object 0.9.8 (this is what gem install page-object gives me)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely with the version. I've been using page object for a while in my projects and never encountered this problem. I'm using the latest version on [RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/gems/page-object/) which is 1.0.3. You might want to tell explicitly RubyGems which version to install ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026441/how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-a-ruby-gem) might be useful).

Comment: That as my first thought, i originally had 1.0.3 did a gem install page-object which gave me 0.9.8 uninstalled it and re-installed 1.0.3 I still get the warning:

Comment: That as my first thought, i originally had 1.0.3 did a gem install page-object which gave me 0.9.8 uninstalled it and re-installed 1.0.3 I still get the warning:<br>*** DEPRECATION WARNING
*** You are calling a method named search_type_lst= at c:/my_proj/features/step_definitions/test.rb:100:in 'block in (top (required))
*** This method does not exist in page-object so it is being passed to the driver.
*** This feature will be removed in the near future.
*** Please change your code to call the correct page-object method.
*** If you are using functionality that does not exist in page-object