# Ruby. Errors. DataMapper

Tags: ruby, selenium, datamapper

Try to use DataMapper on my macbook and got such error:

```
/Users/roger/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems
/specification.rb:2288:in `raise_if_conflicts':

Unable to activate dm-serializer-1.2.2, because json-2.1.0 conflicts 
with json (~> 1.6) (Gem::ConflictError)
```

I try to uninstall JSON and install new. But if before ruby complain about JSON 1.6 now it complain about 2.10.
What to do I don't know..

Same script on my Ubuntu server work with DataMapper without problem but got Selenium error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:158:in `rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:136:in `readuntil'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/protocol.rb:146:in `readline'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http/response.rb:40:in `read_status_line'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http/response.rb:29:in `read_new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1437:in `block in transport_request'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1434:in `catch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1434:in `transport_request'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1407:in `request'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1400:in `block in request'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:853:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:1398:in `request'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:124:in `response_for'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:78:in `request'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:61:in `call'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:170:in `execute'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:103:in `create_session'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/marionette/driver.rb:56:in `initialize'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/driver.rb:33:in `new'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/driver.rb:33:in `new'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.3/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:54:in `for'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.4.3/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:86:in `for'
    from selen_serv.rb:19:in `<main>'
```

Script header:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'rspec/expectations'
require 'headless'
require 'pp'
require 'json'
require 'rubygems'

require 'data_mapper'
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-validations'
require 'dm-timestamps'

TEST_DIR = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
TEST_FILES = File.join(TEST_DIR, "test_files")
TEST_OUTPUT = File.join(TEST_DIR, "test_output")
CHROMEDRIVER_FN = File.join(File.absolute_path('..', TEST_DIR), "/usr/local/bin", "chromedriver")

@browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox


bash-3.2$ bundler
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "json_pure":
  In Gemfile:
    data_mapper was resolved to 1.2.0, which depends on
      dm-serializer (~> 1.2.0) was resolved to 1.2.2, which depends on
        json_pure (~> 1.6)

Could not find gem 'json_pure (~> 1.6)', which is required by gem 'dm-serializer (~> 1.2.0)', in any of the sources.
```

Comment: First of all post 2 questions, one for ruby and one for python

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3414337/1743811) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026441/how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-a-ruby-gem) regarding the json gem error.

Comment: @doubleDown you think I should install 1.6 JSON? But where it was installed ruby complain about it. What to do IDK.

Comment: @rogersnest `~ 1.6` means 1.X that is 1.6 or newer (that's why 2.1.0 doesn't work). You should update the question to say what error you get when you use 1.6.

Comment: I do uninstall gem uninstall json
-----
gem uninstall json
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    json is not installed in GEM_HOME, try:
 gem uninstall -i /Users/roger/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global json

-----
But after!!! gem list stil shows json (2.1.0, default: 2.0.2, 1.8.6)
Maybe I should delete it by hand?

Comment: Guyz help me to delete this fkn gem by hand. I got macos as I said before, and I visit ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems and delete 2.1.0 but gem list stiil show this gem.... where is it fkn sht?

Comment: Guyz tell me please how can I delete with 100% guarantee some gem in MACOS?

Comment: sudo gem uninstall json -v 2.1.0
Successfully uninstalled json-2.1.0
------

Comment: sudo gem uninstall json -v 2.1.0
Successfully uninstalled json-2.1.0
------
sudo gem uninstall json -v 2.1.0
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError  gem "json" is not installed
-----
gem list | grep 'json'
json (2.1.0, default: 2.0.2)
json_pure (1.6.0)
multi_json (1.12.1)
-----
Result I CANT UNINSTALL JSON 2.1.0 I just don't know how. MACOS don't forget.

Comment: I used MC and search for json-2.1.0 and delete all files include docs. And now MC doesn't show any json-2.1.0 file BUT gem shows installed 2.1.0 ((((((((((((

Comment: simple guyz. gem uninstall gem --all
I uninstall this 2.1.0 but now I got another problem, cant install Mysql
gem install mysql - and 4 pages of errors and warnings and as result no installed module