# Bundler installed but errors out saying it is not installed

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm using RVM, currently I'm using ruby 2.7.4

```
rvm current
ruby-2.7.4
```

I installed bundler -v 2.2.26 as default

```
gem install bundler -v2.2.26 --default
gem info bundler
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (2.2.26)
    Authors: André Arko, Samuel Giddins, Colby Swandale, Hiroshi
    Shibata, David Rodríguez, Grey Baker, Stephanie Morillo, Chris
    Morris, James Wen, Tim Moore, André Medeiros, Jessica Lynn Suttles,
    Terence Lee, Carl Lerche, Yehuda Katz
    Homepage: https://bundler.io
    License: MIT
    Installed at (default): /Users/jedrek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
```

When I check the location of the gem, it is not there.

```
ls /Users/jedrek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems
# no bundler gem
```

When I try to `bundle` my gems in my project I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    3: from /Users/jedrek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
    2: from /Users/jedrek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
    1: from /Users/jedrek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
/Users/jedrek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.4/bin/bundle:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/jedrek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.26/exe/bundle (LoadError)
```

Where is my gem? What's going on?

Comment: what is the output of `gem list bundler` ?

Comment: I found in the internet that you can do `gem install bundler:2.2.26` and now it works. Very confusing. I still don't understand why it didn't work before.
```
gem list bundler

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (default: 2.2.27, 2.2.24, 2.1.4, 1.17.3, 1.14.0)
```

Comment: Install the gem version with either syntax doesn't make a difference. My guess is you have multiple projects using different versions and perhaps you're switching around is not working as expected. You may want to try gemsets or chruby instead. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on if you have multiple projects on your system, when using RVM you may want to look into [using gem sets](https://rvm.io/gemsets/using) as this can help with using correct versions when switching between project.  However if you don't care about that, you can try uninstall the gem, then reinstall the version you want.

```
gem uninstall bundler # should uninstall all versions besides

#either of these two work the same
gem install bundler:2.2.26 
gem install bundler -v2.2.26
```

Personally I switched from using RVM to [Chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby#chruby) quite some time ago and have had far fewer issues like the one you described here.

Comment: Thanks. The syntax does make a difference because I tried installing with -v option and it didn't work. I installed with : syntax and it worked. I don't know why, though.

Comment: @jedi are you using an outdated version of ruby? see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026441/ruby-how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-a-ruby-gem) for reference seems : syntax is for 1.9+ but still supported in 2.x

Comment: I am using ruby 2.7.4 with RVM