# Beta version of gem not recognized by Bundler as resolving dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to add the [fuubar gem](https://github.com/jeffkreeftmeijer/fuubar) to my Gemfile, but I am using a beta version of `rspec-rails` and Bundler can't find compatible dependencies for both.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.0.beta1'
gem 'fuubar', '>= 1.3.2'
```

Fuubar depends on `rspec < 3.1.0, >= 2.14.0`. From [what I understand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19206923/454094), `3.0.0.beta1` should match that requirement. The error I get is as follows:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rspec-mocks":
  In Gemfile:
    rspec (< 3.1.0, >= 2.14.0) x86-mingw32 depends on
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.14.0) x86-mingw32

    rspec-rails (~> 3.0.0.beta1) ruby depends on
      rspec-mocks (3.0.0.beta1)
```

Is `x86-mingw32` the key here? Something like no beta version being available for that platform, or..?

Comment: `3.0.0.beta1` satisfies to `< 3.1.0` but you have problem with `rspec-mocks`. What is your reason to define `rspec-rails` as `~> 3.0.0.beta1`? Maybe try update gems for testing.

Comment: The beta version has features that I want to use. The specific gems are not important to the question, I'm interested in how Bundler tries to resolve a dependency situation like this and why it does not recognize that [`rspec 3.0.0.beta1` would satisfy the requirements](https://rubygems.org/gems/rspec/versions/3.0.0.beta1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to install the gems. If I explicitly add `gem 'rspec', '~> 3.0.0.beta1'` to my Gemfile, Bundler happily installs everything. Maybe Bundler avoids pre-release versions unless they are specifically asked for.

Since the dependency tree gets stored in Gemfile.lock, I can even remove the above line from my Gemfile and a subsequent `bundle install` will succeed. Not sure about `bundle update`, but I always update gems one by one anyway.

This does not answer the question of *why*, however. If someone can explain it, or point me to documentation that shows this as the intended way of working, I can readily make that the accepted answer.