# Active_Model error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I went back to a rails project I was working on and the command "rails s" started to fail. The Terminal recommended that I run a bundle install. When I did I received the following message:

```
    Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
    In Gemfile:
    protected_attributes (>= 0) ruby depends on
    activemodel (< 5.0, >= 4.0.0.beta) ruby

    rails (>= 0) ruby depends on
    activemodel (3.2.12)
```

I have updated both ruby and rails. I've re-installed active model and restarted my terminal.

My gems file is very simple:

```
 gem 'rails'
 gem 'jquery-rails'
 gem 'devise'
 gem 'simple_form'
 gem 'protected_attributes'

group :production do
gem 'pg' 
  end

 group :development, :test do 
gem 'sqlite3'
  end

  group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
   gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
   gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.2.2.0'
   gem 'bootstrap'
   end
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove your Gemfile.lock and run

- rm Gemfile.lock

  and
- bundle install

Comment: It worked!

Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to vote up your answer :(

If someone could do it for me that would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: You should still accept the answer that worked for you even if you can't up vote.

Answer (score 1):

Remove Gemfile.lock

and then bundle 
if not works then specify rails version in gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried running

```
gem update activemodel
```

or

```
bundle update
```

Comment: Yup!

gem update:
    Updating installed gems
    Nothing to update

bundle update:
    protected_attributes (>= 0) ruby depends on
      activemodel (< 5.0, >= 4.0.0.beta) ruby

    coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1) ruby depends on
      activemodel (3.2.0.rc1)

Answer (score 0):

Bundler has attempted to install Rails 4 and associated gems, but you have some gems fixed at earlier incompatible versions. Either specify a 3.x.x version of Rails or remove the version requirements on your `sass-rails` and `coffee-rails` gems.

(I took your Gemfile into a sample application and attempted to run a `bundle install`--I didn't get the exact error you're seeing but an error of the same cause. Removing the version requirements on those gems solved the issue. Of course that may not be appropriate for your needs!)

Comment: This is most likely the case (about version specification). It's likely that activemodel isn't being updated to the version that's required because of the specificity of the assets gems. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170547/what-does-tilde-greater-than-mean-in-ruby-gem-dependencies/5170592#5170592

Comment: I got only one error when I did this. However instead of trying to figure out why I removed the Gemfile.lock as suggested by another user. Thanks for the help though!