# Installing redcarpet gem on mavericks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, redcarpet, osx-mavericks

I'm currently trying to install Redcarpet gem for a rails project.

The problem is that a few days ago I upgraded to Mavericks OS and I'm not able to install it, but I'm not really sure if it has anything to do with the change of OS.

Here's the errors I'm getting:

```
ERROR:  Error installing redcarpet:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/lalala/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile
make
compiling autolink.c
In file included from autolink.c:17:
buffer.h:23:20: error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
In file included from autolink.c:17:
buffer.h:41: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘uint8_t’
In file included from autolink.c:18:
autolink.h:31: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘uint8_t’
autolink.h:31: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
autolink.h:35: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘uint8_t’
autolink.h:39: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘uint8_t’
autolink.h:43: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘uint8_t’
autolink.c:20:20: error: string.h: No such file or directory
autolink.c:21:20: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
autolink.c:22:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
autolink.c:23:19: error: ctype.h: No such file or directory
autolink.c:30: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘uint8_t’
autolink.c:30: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
autolink.c:52: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
autolink.c:136: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
autolink.c:165: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘uint8_t’
autolink.c: In function ‘sd_autolink__www’:
autolink.c:172: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘ispunct’
autolink.c:172: error: ‘data’ undeclared (first use in this function)
autolink.c:172: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
autolink.c:172: error: for each function it appears in.)
autolink.c:172: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘isspace’
autolink.c:175: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘memcmp’
autolink.c:175: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strlen’
autolink.c:175: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
autolink.c:178: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘check_domain’
autolink.c:186: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘autolink_delim’
autolink.c: At top level:
autolink.c:201: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘uint8_t’
autolink.c: In function ‘sd_autolink__email’:
autolink.c:210: error: ‘uint8_t’ undeclared (first use in this function)
autolink.c:210: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘c’
autolink.c:212: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘isalnum’
autolink.c:212: error: ‘c’ undeclared (first use in this function)
autolink.c:215: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strchr’
autolink.c:215: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strchr’
autolink.c:225: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘c’
autolink.c:241: error: ‘data’ undeclared (first use in this function)
autolink.c: At top level:
autolink.c:256: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘uint8_t’
autolink.c: In function ‘sd_autolink__url’:
autolink.c:263: error: ‘data’ undeclared (first use in this function)
autolink.c:266: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘isalpha’
autolink.c:269: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘sd_autolink_issafe’
autolink.c:272: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
make: *** [autolink.o] Error 1
```

Apparently there's a problem with some of the c libraries, however I have no idea how to fix it, I've been googling but haven't found anything useful.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you tried upgrading to the latest XCode?

You might need to be running XCode version 5.0.1 to compile native extensions under Mavericks. 
[Link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12).

**Edit:**

As @Doon points out in his comment, you may need to run

```
xcode-select --install
```

to get the latest command-line tools.

Comment: xcode-select --install to get the command line tools and see if that helps.

Comment: Doon, that's what I did and it's working =), I'm waiting 6 hours to post the answer (won't let me do it before as I don't have 10 rep points yet :P)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Ok I finally found out that when I upgraded to 10.9 Mavericks my gcc was broken, so I had to install the command line tools.

How to do it:

1) Open Terminal

2) Type in "xcode-select --install" (without the quotes)

3) Press enter

4) Click on "Install"

That's it!

Comment: Except this gives an error saying not available on the server.  It goes to Finding Software progress bar then "Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server."

Comment: When this happened I didn't get any errors, it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to remove your Gemfile.lock and run a bundle install again?

See this answer:

[Active_Model error in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19530913/active-model-error-in-rails/19531010#19531010)

Hope this helps!