# How to update sass along with bootstrap-sass in my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, bundler, gemfile, bootstrap-sass

In `Gemfile` I had:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.0.3.0'
```

I have now changed it to the following, which is the latest version at the time of this writing:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1.1'
```

Taking a look at both [bootstrap-sass (3.0.3.0)](https://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap-sass/versions/3.0.3.0) and [bootstrap-sass (3.1.1.1)](https://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap-sass/versions/3.1.1.1) on RubyGems.org, I see that both versions have runtime dependencies of:

```
sass ~> 3.2
```

Taking a look at [sass](https://rubygems.org/gems/sass) itself, I see that it has no runtime dependencies, and that its latest version is:

```
gem 'sass', '~> 3.3.7'
```

After making the change mentioned above (to `bootstrap-sass`) I ran `bundle`, and saw the following:

```
...
Using sass 3.2.19
Installing bootstrap-sass 3.1.1.1 (was 3.0.3.0)
...
```

My question is *why wasn't `sass` updated*, and how can I update it without referencing it in `Gemfile`?

For what it's worth, here is some more info:

```
-bash> grep sass Gemfile.lock 
    bootstrap-sass (3.1.1.1)
      sass (~> 3.2)
      sass-rails (~> 4.0)
    sass (3.2.19)
    sass-rails (4.0.3)
      sass (~> 3.2.0)
  bootstrap-sass (~> 3.1.1.1)
  sass-rails (~> 4.0.3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, both `bootstrap-sass` versions (`3.0.3.0` and `3.1.1.1`) have a dependency of:

```
sass ~> 3.2
```

What this means is that they require the highest `3.2.x` version of `sass`, but not `3.3`. That's what the `~>` means, and that is why your sass is `3.2.19`.

So even if you explicitly say:

```
gem 'sass', '~> 3.3.7'
```

Bundler won't update it because it sees that `bootstrap-sass` depends on a lower version of `sass`.

Comment: It happens. Good luck with your project. :)

Comment: > `sass ~> 3.2` ... What this means is that they require the highest 3.2.x version of sass, but not 3.3.

This is not correct. `~> 3.2` means it requires a minimum of 3.2.x up to a maximum of (but not including) 4.0. E.g. It will match 3.3, 3.4, 3.5 etc, but not 4.0 or 4.1.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true. Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170547/what-does-tilde-greater-than-mean-in-ruby-gem-dependencies