# Rails 5 Mongoid - undefined method `scope' for Mongoid::Document:Module (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I recently upgraded to Rails 5 and I've been having some incompatibility issues. I'm getting this error from Mongoid:

```
Error details saved to: /var/folders/mg/zcwvcwhs5wl0bk52dx6p4b180000gn/T//passenger-error-RLaKeF.html
  Message from application: undefined method `scope' for Mongoid::Document:Module (NoMethodError)
  /Users/johnmolina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/kaminari-0.16.3/lib/kaminari/models/mongoid_extension.rb:10:in `block in <module:Document>'
  /Users/johnmolina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/concern.rb:120:in `class_eval'
  /Users/johnmolina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/concern.rb:120:in `append_features'
  /Users/johnmolina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/kaminari-0.16.3/lib/kaminari/hooks.rb:21:in `include'
  /Users/johnmolina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/kaminari-0.16.3/lib/kaminari/hooks.rb:21:in `init'
  /Users/johnmolina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/kaminari-0.16.3/lib/kaminari/railtie.rb:4:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
  /Users/johnmolina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  /Users/johnmolina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  /Users/johnmolina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  /Users/johnmolina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
  /Users/johnmolina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /Users/johnmolina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /Users/johnmolina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /Users/johnmolina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
  /Users/johnmolina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
  /Users/johnmolina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
  /Users/johnmolina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
  /Users/johnmolina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
  /Users/johnmolina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  /Users/johnmolina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
  /Users/johnmolina/Documents/Rails/Nyvur/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /Users/johnmolina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rack-2.0.0.rc1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
  /Users/johnmolina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rack-2.0.0.rc1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /Users/johnmolina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/passenger-5.0.28/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `eval'
  /Users/johnmolina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/passenger-5.0.28/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:110:in `preload_app'
  /Users/johnmolina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/passenger-5.0.28/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /Users/johnmolina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/passenger-5.0.28/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /Users/johnmolina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/passenger-5.0.28/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

I get this error if I add `gem 'mongoid', '~> 5.0.0'` to the Gemfile:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    activemodel (= 5.0.0.rc1)

  In Gemfile:
    annotate was resolved to 2.7.1, which depends on
      activerecord (< 6.0, >= 3.2) was resolved to 5.0.0.rc1, which depends on
        activemodel (= 5.0.0.rc1)

    annotate was resolved to 2.7.1, which depends on
      activerecord (< 6.0, >= 3.2) was resolved to 5.0.0.rc1, which depends on
        activemodel (= 5.0.0.rc1)

    mongoid (~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      activemodel (~> 4.0)

    paperclip was resolved to 4.3.6, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)

    web-console was resolved to 3.1.1, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 4.2)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

I can provide additional information regarding this issue.

Comment: Does Kaminari claim to be compatible with Mongoid 5?

Comment: I think I did stumbled upon a Kaminari issue, I added Kaminari to the Gemfile, but no change. I'm not sure if I should point it to the right dependency version needed. I'll post a Gemfile error here whenever I add `gem 'mongoid', '~> 5.0.0'` to the gemfile, might help.

Comment: So you're mixing Rails5-RC1 (which isn't fully released or production ready) with Mongoid5 and they're tripping over each other with their ActiveModel dependency? The `~> 4.0` for the Mongoid5 dependency [means that it isn't compatible with ActiveModel 5](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5170547/479863) so apparently the Mongoid5 you're using isn't ready for Rails5.

Comment: I see. I installed action-cable as a gem and I'm just going to stick with rails 4.2 for now. Everything seems to be working fine now. Thanks for the reply, really helpful.