# Understanding the tilde operator in Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemfile

I currently have a dependency of the following

```
i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4)
```

I've been having a read through of the [Ruby Gems - Declaring Dependency Guide](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#declaring_dependencies)

And I've found out that the '~> 0.6' part means anything between 0.6 and 1.0 - correct me if that's wrong.

But I'm still confused, what does this actually mean with a second comma separated value?

A colleague believes it means

```
>= 0.6.4, <= 0.7
```

But I'm not so sure.

Comment: It depends on the specified precision: `~> 0.6` means `>= 0.6 and < 1.0` whereas `~> 0.6.4` means `>= 0.6.4 and < 0.7`. Note that the start is always inclusive (>=) and the end is always exclusive (<).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does tilde-greater-than (~>) mean in Ruby gem dependencies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170547/what-does-tilde-greater-than-mean-in-ruby-gem-dependencies)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

short answer: as pointed by Holger in the comments, `~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4` means `>= 0.6.4 and < 1.0`.

The `~>` operator is called [pessimistic operator](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rubys-pessimistic-operator) (or twiddle-wakka), and its objective is to guard the gems from potential bugs/failures in future releases.

When you're building a gem, you must create a special [Specification Class](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/) and put it in a `.gemspec` file or in a Rakefile. This class contains the information for the gem, like its name, version, license and the dependencies.

And is a good practice specify the dependencies following a pessimistic version constraint. Therefore, notations like `~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4` are very common.

You can find more information [here](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#declaring-dependencies).

Comment: The short answer is wrong unfortunately. The specification in the question is the same as `>= 0.6.4, < 1.0`. This is because `~> 0.6` means `>= 0.6, < 1.0` which is then further restricted from the bottom to only allow versions `>= 0.6.4`.

Comment: Well, the OP is explicitly referring to _"the '~> 0.6' part"_