# I installed middleman, but I still have v3.4.1 and not v4 as expected

Tags: middleman, middleman-4

I don't know if I am thinking right, but I couldn't find anything on the web regarding the installation of middleman v4.
I did the installation as explained on Middleman website : https://middlemanapp.com/basics/install/

And my `Gemfile` in my middleman folder is still showing

```
gem "middleman", "~>3.4.1"
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `~>` designation is [preventing your app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170547/what-does-tilde-greater-than-mean-in-ruby-gem-dependencies?noredirect=1&lq=1) from installing any version of the Middleman gem that is higher that 3.5. Try changing that line to something like this:

```
gem "middleman", "~> 4.2"
```

After updating your Gemfile, you'll [need to run](http://bundler.io/v1.2/man/bundle-update.1.html#UPDATING-A-LIST-OF-GEMS) `bundle update middleman` to update the Middleman gem.